# Will Neglected Heirloom ever transform back again?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Neglected Heirloom](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Neglected%20Heirloom) says:

> When equipped creature transforms, transform Neglected Heirloom.

However, on the other side of this sword, there is nothing about transforming the equipment back. Does the transform rule exist, and keep transforming the equipment back and forth with the equipped creature, or does it stay on the once transformed version until stated otherwise by another effect or removed from the battleground?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neglected Heirloom transforms once, into [Ashmouth Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashmouth%20Blade), and stays that way. (Until something exceptional happens, like another effect or removal, like you said.)

The transformation rule on the *Neglected Heirloom* front face doesn't matter once it's transformed. The currently face-up side is all that matters, which is *Ashmouth Blade*. It doesn't have an ability that transforms it, so that's that. *Neglected Heirloom*'s transform ability doesn't exist anymore.

There's several other cards that transform only one way, so this isn't entirely unusual, and for all of those the other face no longer matters. [Ormendahl, Profane Prince](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ormendahl%2C%20Profane%20Prince) doesn't have the mana-generating abilities of [Westvale Abbey](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Westvale%20Abbey) either, for example, and doesn't have anything available to transform it back into a building.

(Also, because of the "no flippy-floppy" rules change [introduced with Shadows over Innistrad](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/shadows-over-innistrad-mechanics), that original ability on its front face can't transform it back and forth if the equipped creature happens to transform multiple times at once.)